# Schengen visa for a 14 year old Ugandan child who does not live with me, to come visit

Tags: schengen-visas, ugandan-citizens

I am residing in Denmark. I have a Danish child here in Denmark and a Ugandan child currently Uganda. My mother-in-law who is a Danish national has invited my Ugandan daughter for a visit with a main purpose of attending her little sister's birthday.

My mother in-law has not included her bank statement saying that the Danish embassy can see her status using her national identity NEM-ID. Is that true? But my child's guardian who is my cousin has included his bank statement, is that okay?

Lastly, I sent my parental consent to my lawyer in Uganda for notarization and I swore a declaration because I don't know her father's whereabouts. Is that okay?

Can you please advise me on what could be so important to include in this application.

Comment: Am I correct in inferring that you are married to a Danish citizen and that your Ugandan daughter is from an earlier relationship?

Comment: Yes that's right